# How to pass array to rdlc report?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports, parameter-passing, rdlc

I provided a radcombobox to let user select one or more than one department to generate a report (developed by asp.net report (RDLC)).

I had developeded the following dataset:

```
SELECT     c.DeptID, c.Department, b.Course_Name, b.Course_ID, b.Type, b.Ref_Code, b.Exam
FROM         dbo.db_Competency_List AS a INNER JOIN
                      dbo.db_Course AS b ON a.Course_ID = b.Course_ID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.db_Department AS c ON a.Dept_ID = c.DeptID
where a.Dept_ID in (@Para_DID)
```

[image]

[image]

It works if user select one department only.

but if user select more than one department, it seems that the dataset cannot get the parameter.
e.g. 12,33,65,78...

Code:

```
    <telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcb_select_dept" runat="server"  DataSourceID="LDS_ddl_dept" DataTextField="Department" AutoPostBack="True" 
           DefaultMessage="Please Select" DataValueField="DeptID" Width="300" CheckBoxes="true" 
           AllowCustomText="true" >
    </telerik:RadComboBox>
       <asp:LinqDataSource ID="LDS_ddl_dept" runat="server" 
           ContextTypeName="dcLRDBDataContext" EntityTypeName="" TableName="db_Departments" OrderBy="Department">
       </asp:LinqDataSource>
       </td>
   </tr>
   </table>

   <br />

   <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Width="1200px" 
                       Height="800px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" 
                       InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" 
                       WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt">
                       <LocalReport ReportPath="Reports\template\RequiredByDepartment.rdlc">
                         <DataSources>
                              <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="ObjectDataSource1" 
                                    Name="DS_Content" />           
                              </DataSources>
                       </LocalReport>
                   </rsweb:ReportViewer>
<br />

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" 
    OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetData" 
    TypeName="LRDBDataSetTableAdapters.vReqByDeptTableAdapter">
    <SelectParameters>
                <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="0" Name="Para_DID" Type="String" />                        
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Code behind:

```
Protected Sub rtbMenu_ButtonClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Telerik.Web.UI.RadToolBarEventArgs) Handles rtbMenu.ButtonClick
    If e.Item.Value = "Generate" Then

        'Get DID
        Dim strCOM_cmb As String = ""

        For i = 0 To rcb_select_dept.CheckedItems.Count - 1
            If rcb_select_dept.CheckedItems(i).Checked = True Then
                strCOM_cmb += rcb_select_dept.CheckedItems(i).Value.ToString & ","
            End If
        Next
        If Left(strCOM_cmb, 1) = "," Then
            strCOM_cmb = Right(strCOM_cmb, Len(strCOM_cmb) - 1)
        End If
        If Right(strCOM_cmb, 1) = "," Then
            strCOM_cmb = Left(strCOM_cmb, Len(strCOM_cmb) - 1)
        End If
        strCOM_cmb = TrimList(strCOM_cmb)

        Dim params(0) As Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter
        params(0) = New Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter("Para_DID", strCOM_cmb)
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(params)

        ObjectDataSource1.SelectParameters("Para_DID").DefaultValue = strCOM_cmb
        ObjectDataSource1.DataBind()

        Preview()
    End If
End Sub

Sub Preview()

    ReportViewer1.Visible = True
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh()

End Sub
```

How can i pass the department ID array (parameter) to the report ?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to handle this issue in SQL implementation. Just the optional.

To pass text parameter and hope it works as a list, you should represent them in table, after then join your query result to that list in the table. See code below:

Create new table variable and insert each member in the list into the table:

```
DECLARE @SelectedDeptIds table
(
    DeptID int
)

DECLARE @deptIdTemp varchar(10), @Pos int

SET @Para_DID = LTRIM(RTRIM(@Para_DID))+ ','
SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(',', @Para_DID, 1)

IF REPLACE(@Para_DID, ',', '') <> ''
BEGIN
        WHILE @Pos > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @deptIdTemp = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@Para_DID, @Pos - 1)))
        IF @deptIdTemp <> ''
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @SelectedDeptIds (DeptID) VALUES (CAST(@deptIdTemp AS int))
        END
        SET @Para_DID = RIGHT(@Para_DID, LEN(@Para_DID) - @Pos)
        SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(',', @Para_DID, 1)
    END
END
```

Next code is to join table to the list:

```
SELECT     c.DeptID, c.Department, b.Course_Name, b.Course_ID, b.Type, b.Ref_Code, b.Exam
FROM       dbo.db_Competency_List AS a INNER JOIN
           dbo.db_Course AS b ON a.Course_ID = b.Course_ID INNER JOIN
           dbo.db_Department AS c ON a.Dept_ID = c.DeptID
INNER JOIN @SelectedDeptIds d ON a.Dept_ID = d.DeptID
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this is to pass your array of values as a comma separated string (or another delimiter if you wish), then split that within the report. As far as I'm aware there isn't a simpler way to pass multiple values as a single parameter to a report.

Answer (score 0):

i create a tmp table.

it delete the existing DeptID (where UserID = who generate the report) first
and then insert the selected DeptID and UserID to the tmp table in code behind.

and then amend the dataset:

```
SELECT     c.DeptID, c.Department, b.Course_Name, b.Course_ID, b.Type, b.Ref_Code, b.Exam, a.RoleType_ID
FROM         dbo.db_Competency_List AS a INNER JOIN
                      dbo.db_Course AS b ON a.Course_ID = b.Course_ID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.db_Department AS c ON a.Dept_ID = c.DeptID
where a.Dept_ID in (SELECT id from dbo.db_tmp_rpt where UserID=@UserID)
```